# Include code for plots in an R Notebook output

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

This feels like it should be really straightforward, but I can't work out how to include the code used to create a plot in an R Notebook (i.e. above the plot it creates). Confusingly, some online examples (eg the one immediately below, from [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html#fig:notebook-preview)) show the plot code being included automatically in the `html_notebook` output, but other sources (eg the bottom image, from [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html) show the code for the plot being hidden (which is the behaviour I am getting at the moment). I am aware that the bottom example is a `html_document` output and not a `html_notebook` and that there are differences between the two, but in any case I am using a `html_notebook` but seeing the behaviour in the second image.

I have tried the different chunk options listed [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/) and [here](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) (eg `echo=TRUE`) but to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: example showing what I want]

[image: example showing what I get at the moment]

Answer (score 1):

The first document uses the `code_folding: show` YAML option with chunck option `echo = T`:

```
---
title: "Notebook"
output:
  html_notebook:
    code_folding: show
  html_document:
    code_folding: show
---
```

[image]

The second document just uses global chunk option `echo = F`:

````
---
title: "Notebook"
output:
  html_document
---

`r knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)`

```{r}
plot(1)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks – do you know if there is a way to get this to work for `output: html_notebook` (not `html_document`)? I can get it to work for [document](https://i.imgur.com/iwLX6oX.png), but not for [notebook](https://i.imgur.com/3iDnSfn.png), which is what I want.

Comment: See my edit : I added the same YAML for `html_notebook` and `html_document` and it now seems to work as expected. When just setting `html_notebook` YAML, RStudio automatically inserts a new `html_document` YAML at the first `knit to HTML`

Comment: Thanks – I've copied your YAML but I'm still getting the same behaviour as before (like [this](https://i.imgur.com/wxCYCfA.png)) – do you know what I need to change?

Comment: What happens if you knit to html? You also don't seem to be using the latest [RStudio 1.4 version](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download)

Comment: Just tried and it works if I knit it (so to a `html_document`), but not if I preview the notebook (so to a `html_notebook`). Maybe this is just a feature, but it would be nice to be able to save it to a .nb.html but still show the plot code above the plots.

Comment: AFAIK, preview uses data from previous knit. So after knitting once, preview shows code + plot in my case.

Comment: Hmm, for me I can knit it and get the code + plot, but as soon as I switch to preview the code disappears. I've updated my RStudio version so I don't think it's that.

Comment: We're missing something here, and I stuck ;)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help in any case, it's not the end of the world if I use `html_document` instead (or don't see the code for the plots)